# How to show price of dropdown menu in a DIV

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu as follows

```
<option value="Small">small</option>
<option value="Medium">medium</option>
<option value="Large">large</option>
```

When a user selects one of the above I want a DIV below the dropdown which shows the price when selected. Any help would be great. jsfiddle.

Comment: You need Javascript for that sort of thing. We won't write it for you, but if you show you've at least TRIED it yourself, we'll try to help fix it.

Comment: if i new where to start I would have tried it but I dont hence why im asking

Comment: Where does the price come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. You could have the price in a data attribute and then put it in the div:

```
<select onChange="document.getElementById('price').firstChild.nodeValue
                     =this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-price');">
  <option data-price="$3.00">Small</option>
  <option data-price="$3.50">Medium</option>
  <option data-price="$4.00">Large</option>
</select>
<div id="price">$3.00</div>
```

Note that I removed the `value` attributes. It defaults to the text of the option, so it was redundant to put it there twice.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/TpXAa/

Comment: awesome, thanks so much. I like a straight answer like the above.

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't get a dozen downvotes for reasons like "using an inline event handler" and "not using jQuery". Because, of course, [jQuery is the answer to everything](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/178220)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use jQuery.

I would go with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.group').hide();
     $('#option1').show();
     $('#selectMe').change(function () {
         $('.group').hide();
         $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
     })
});


<select id="selectMe">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
<div id="option1" class="group">$ 0</div>
<div id="option2" class="group">$ 10</div>
<div id="option3" class="group">$ 20</div>
<div id="option4" class="group">$ 50</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $('#lbl').text($('#select1').val())

    $('#select1').on('change', function() {
        $('#lbl').text($(this).val())
    });
});
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/DRwEN/)